# Change body background image when page is running

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to change my background color while the page is running. I have coded it in JS but no result. JQuery is included on the head section.

```
 <ul>
            <li><a href="#" onClick=="one()"><img src="img/dot_active.png" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onClick=="two()"><img src="img/dot_inactive.png" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onClick=="three()"><img src="img/dot_inactive.png" /></a></li>
 </ul>
```

And this is my JS.

```
<script>

function one(){
$('body').css('background-image','url(img/1.jpg');
}

function two(){
document.getElementById('body').style.backgroundImage = 'url(img/1b.jpg)';
}

function three(){
$('body').css('background-image','url("img/1c.jpg"');
}

</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by page is running?

Answer (score 6):

A typo in your code

```
onClick=="one()"
       ^
```

---

### NitPick time:

Since you are using jQuery, why are you using inline event handlers?

Use a single click handler and data attributes

HTML:

```
<ul id="foo">
   <li><a href="#" data-bg="img/1.jpg">A</a></li>
   <li><b href="#" data-bg="img/1b.jpg">B</a></li>
   <li><c href="#" data-bg="img/1c.jpg">C</a></li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript: *(attached on document ready)*

```
$("#foo").on("click","a", function(evt) { //attach clickc to parent ul and look for click on the anchor
    evt.preventDefault();  //cancel click
    var anchor = $(this);  //get link that was clicked
    var bgImg = anchor.data("bg"); //get the data attribute value from the clicked link
    $("body").css("background-image", "url(" + bgImg + ")");   //set the image
});
```

Comment: Wow, I cant believe ive been working on this for an hour. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage="url('img/1.jpg')";
```

Comment: I accidentally put "==" instead of "=", that was my problem. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Please avoid guesses when providing an answer. Answers should be reserved for *solutions* that you *know* are working. Also consider adding an explanation; currently this is a code-only (and therefore low-quality) answer.